# How to run Facebook's curl codes?

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-opengraph

Im new to php n curl.. Im going to use Facebook's OGP for my facebook app that im using in my website..I created OPG setings for publish my app activities to the users profile.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/

After i have setup accouring to the Tutorial(above url) they give me curl code like

```
curl -F 'access_token=AAACAwq1JHZA0BAA94uB50n7O71B6PmMUsFAydKBKCv1HcdJw9NwK8MZC83vL2YqUXojQ0aXH8EBjTweKHQTr4bZBKlgkOJ0nB5dBDu6A09UbI0lmXZBs' \
     -F 'friend=http://samples.ogp.me/205849716166552' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/yalumalu:add'
```

and

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/yalumalu:add?access_token=AAACAwq1JHZA0BAA94uB50n7O71B6PmMUsFAydKBKCv1HcdJw9NwK8MZC83vL2YqUXojQ0aXH8EBjTweKHQTr4bZBKlgkOJ0nB5dBDu6A09UbI0lmXZBs'
```

I don't know how to run these codes in my site..Tutorial says something else there no curl codes in tutorial that given by facebook.. I tried alot.. Someone please help me to do this..

Comment: That depends on your server-side technology. Plain html won't do.

Comment: yh its aftr long time..thanks 4 helping me..now i knw fb codes runs on thier own platform nw im a little expert in these kinda codes..thnks my friend n i love this place alott..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is a simple way to HTTP GET/POST/DELETE requests.

If you need to achieve similar behaviour in your site you need to choose a language that supports sending these requests.

For example you can use PHP and cURL options as well as the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) or you can use JavaScript to do the same with the [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)